# How to dynamically create an object of a custom label class and add it to the canvas in WPF?

Tags: wpf, label, dynamically-generated

I have found a class of `Label` which adds the functionality of dragging and resizing the `Label` to it. And I don't know how I can dynamically (like by pressing a button which says "create a label") create an object of that class and add it to the `Canvas` of my WPF application.

I also want to specify some of it's properties like width, height, name, content etc. before/after adding it to the `Canvas`.

How is it done the proper way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   //adding new MyLabel(class of Label)
   MyLabel lbl = new MyLabel();
   lbl.Text = "test text";
   lbl.Height = 27;
   lbl.Name="testLabel";
   canvas.Children.Add(lbl);
```

About getting element by name after creating you can read here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Create a new Label instance, set some of its properties, set its position on the Canvas and add it to the Canvas' Children collection:

```
var label = new Label
{
    Width = 200,
    Height = 50,
    Content = "A Label"
};

Canvas.SetLeft(label, 100);
Canvas.SetTop(label, 100);

canvas.Children.Add(label);
```